# AngularJS Directive, Change template after user input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a directive which when initially created gives just a dropdown to select different types of something. Once the user chooses the type, I want to change the template.

I have tried using the below. In my linking function

```
scope.nrAttrs = attrs;
scope.layerIndex = attrs.index;

scope.$watch(function () {
  var currentSlate = scope.$parent.$parent.current_slate_index;
  return scope.$parent.$parent.stage.slates[currentSlate].layers[scope.layerIndex].type;
}, function (oldVal, newVal, scope) {
  htmlReplace(newVal, scope.nrEle, scope);
});
```

The htmlReplace function is:

```
var htmlReplace = function (layerType, element, scope) {
$http.get(layerPartials[layerType]).success(function (tplContent) {
  element.html($compile(tplContent)(scope));
});
```

};

However, I see the watch triggering, but the template stays the same.

Any advice or more information needed?

Edit: @Fals I added the compile but I still see the same result. Is there something else I might be missing?

Comment: You must $compile the element

Comment: sounds like you're looking for ngSwitch

Comment: @Jony-Y Can you explain how that would work? or maybe show a small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as requested here is an example of ngSwitch:

```
<form class="form-horizontal row" name="createProfileForm" role="form" novalidate>
                <div ng-switch on="createProfileState" class="fill">
                    <div ng-switch-when="user">
                        <ng-include src="'views/templates/login/create-account/td-create-account-user.html'"></ng-include>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-switch-when="tutor">
                        <ng-include src="'views/templates/login/create-account/td-create-account-tutor.html'"></ng-include>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

we use the "on" to specify which scope argument is in charge of the changes and then according to the specific values we can use ng-include to render the different templates, naturally they will all run in the same controller and scope

Comment: Will try it this way now and report back.

Comment: I tried this, but when I update the switch on value, the template stays at the default.

Comment: This worked, the error was because of an html comment -_-